# Calculate Running Average Using DAX in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following values in `Table_1`:

```
date             sales_amount
04/01/2021       100.00
04/02/2021       300.00
04/05/2021       500.00
```

I want to compute a running average, so the average is computed as each day passes, so that my final output looks like this:

```
date             sales_amount       running_average
04/01/2021       100.00             100.00
04/02/2021       300.00             200.00
04/05/2021       500.00             300.00
```

The sales person did not work on `04/03` and `04/04`, so I want to exclude them from my running average.

Right now, my output looks like this, which is wrong for what I am doing:

```
date             sales_amount       running_average
04/01/2021       100.00             100.00
04/02/2021       300.00             200.00
04/05/2021       500.00             180.00
```

Any suggestions?

Right now, my DAX code looks like this:

```
test_new = 

VAR LastVisibleDate = MAX('Table_1'[Date])
VAR FirstVisibleDate = MIN('Table_1'[Date])
VAR LastDateWithSales = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Table_1'[Date]),
        REMOVEFILTERS()
    )

VAR Result = 
    IF (
        FirstVisibleDate <= LastDateWithSales,
        CALCULATE(
            AVERAGE([Sales_Amount]),
            Table_1[Date]
        )
    )

RETURN
Result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a few lines in the last variable:

1. Table_1[Date] in the last variable basically means FILTER ( ALL ( Table_1[Date] ), TRUE ), and that will return all of the dates so not useful in your scenario as it will give wrong results, instead write Table_1[Date] <= LastVisibleDate
2. You don't need REMOVEFILTERS when you have Date column coming from the Dates table and the Date table is marked as a Date table because when a date table is marked as a date table the engine automatically adds a REMOVEFILTERS/ALL whenever a filter is applied over the Date column, but that won't happen with Date column of other tables hence you need to write an explicit REMOVEFILTERS in the last variable

```
test_new =
VAR LastVisibleDate =
    MAX ( 'Table_1'[Date] )
VAR FirstVisibleDate =
    MIN ( 'Table_1'[Date] )
VAR LastDateWithSales =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table_1'[Date] ),
        REMOVEFILTERS ()
    )
VAR Result =
    IF (
        FirstVisibleDate <= LastDateWithSales,
        CALCULATE (
            AVERAGE ( [Sales_Amount] ),
            Table_1[Date] <= LastVisibleDate,
            REMOVEFILTERS ( Table_1 )
        )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

As a best practice always use Date column from a Date table.

Comment: Just to complement @AntrikshSharma answer check out the following dax pattern https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/

Comment: Thanks you, I will try your solution tonight.